# Tie two objects

Tags: c++, object, sfml

I have to SFML object classes: `Textbox.h` and `ErrorProvider.h`, I defined two objects `TB_Input`(Textbox) and `EP_Note`(ErrorProvider).
When `Textbox` raises `ErrorProvider` it results in a drawn red circle.

I'm trying to tie the two toghether, let me explain:
`TB_Input` and `EP_Note` both have to remember they're tied to each other.

The code I have right now:

```
//Function to tie 2 objects
template<typename ObjectType1, typename ObjectType2>
inline void tie(ObjectType1& obj_1, ObjectType2& obj_2) {
    obj_1.tieTo(obj_2);
    obj_2.tieTo(obj_1);
}
```

Pseudo-code for what I need:

```
// Inside both classes

template<typename ObjectType>
void tieTo(ObjectType link_object) {
    <Unknown Type> variable_that_stores_the_tiedTo_object = link_object;
}
```

> Since I the two tied objects can change I can't use fixed type, so I''m using templates.

Comment: you can have internal pointer to each them, and then make it point to what it tieds to or from.... or if im understanding it wrong then can you make more example?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing more research I found out that the best way is using pointers.
Both classes now have an internal void pointer that points to the tied object, I then dereference it and use it as a normal object.

If you need a better idea I'll leave the code here, also feel free to ask me anything.

---

`Button.h`:

```
void tieTo(ObjectType& object) {
    PTR_tiedTo = &object;

    setPosition(object.getPosition().x + object.getSize().x + EP_offset, 
                object.getPosition().y + (object.getSize().y - radius*2)/2);
}

void ErrorProvider::raise(bool value) {
    raised = value;
}


// PTR Definition:
void *PTR_tiedTo;
```

`Textbox.h`:

```
//Same tieTo() function template toghether with this:

void Textbox::setEP(bool value) {
    ErrorProvider *EP_ptr = static_cast<ErrorProvider*>(PTR_tiedTO);
    EP_ptr->raise(value);
}
```